# React state not setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it seems as if this set of code is not updating my state, and I am not sure why! The api is 100% sending back TRUE (as seen from axios console.log). Thank you advanced for the help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export class Test extends Component {
state = {
    reponse: false
}

componentDidMount () {
    axios.get(`/api`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.success);
            this.setState({ response: res.data.success });
        });
  }

render() {
    if (this.state.reponse) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Response Gathered!</h1>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.reponse)}>Check State</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Why you have to export 2 times

Comment: I fixed that, no sure why that happened. I'm using ES7 for Visual Studio Code!

Comment: fixed what? still have two exports, and it will give you an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change,

```
state = {
    reponse: false
}
```

To,

```
  state = {
    response: false
 }
```

There is a typo in state declaration (reponse to re**s**ponse)..

And modified code would look like,

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    response: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`/api`)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.success);
        this.setState({ response: res.data.success });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.response) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Response Gathered!</h1>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.response)}>
            Check State
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Test;
```

[**Working Codesandbox example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/movie-finder-api-calls-with-react-and-axios-n3vj1)

Answer (score 0):

define `state` in the constructor function.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {response: false};
  }
```

btw, there was a spelling error.

Comment: this is wrong, not sure who is upvoting this, I downvoted

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. Also, is there a need for super(props)?

Comment: if use constructor, `super` is necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    return (
        {this.state.response ? 
          <h1>Some text</h1> : 
          (<div>
              <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.response)}>
                 Check State
               </button>
           </div>)
        }
    );
  }
```